# is it possible to create an OBIEE Analytics on user activity report?

Tags: monitoring, obiee, user-activity

I am a BI administrator and author on my OBIEE (12.2.1.3.0). I need to create an analytics on **users' browsing history**. And then share it to their manager **who is just another normal user himself** (not an administrator). So I searched on Google for a solution. but, I didn't find anything other than "Manage Sessions" section in administration. However, that just shows online sessions, but I need the report per user and their last login time and browsing information. Besides, I don't want to give the manager administration privilege to access this section. instead, I want to create an analytics for him. but for analytics **I need a relevant "Subject Area"**. I don't know if there is a table in OBIEE repository where I can query from. or generally, I might be thinking incorrectly and there are other ways to handle this kind of requirement. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually yes, it is possible. As you may know, OBIEE repository tables,  which can be used to show to end users as subject area that this is usgae tracking utility, just track information around sent queries to BI server and not more about users specifically. 
In this occasion, you can use a method which called enhanced usage tracking for OBIEE that is presented completely here:
https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/12/enhanced-usage-tracking-for-obiee-now-available-as-open-source/

This is exactly what you want. All detail information about users activities in OBIEE and enve some redundant ones. You can create a physical table, then add it to repository file and display as subject area to end user with any permission.
Of course, according to your software environment or implementation structure, you are supposed to make some changes in this manner.

I hope this goes well.

Comment: thanks Atefeh, although I was looking for basic usage tracking, you shared even more. kheili mamnoon. :)